# Is there a way to read what is copied to a user's clipboard, and paste it into the console with javascript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am wondering if there is a way to read what is copied to a user's clipboard and paste it into the console in dev tools.

Comment: You can use [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this:

```
let text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
console.log(text)
```

if you want it to repeat every ten seconds:

```
setInterval(async function(){let text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
console.log(text)
}, 10000)
```